# How to list.sort(memberFunction);?

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I'd like to use the `sort` function of `std::list`, and sort with the member function of "myClass" that contains a property I want to use while sorting.

```
struct  node
{
  int   value;
}

class myClass
{
private:
 bool _available;

public:
 myClass();
 ~myClass();

private:
 bool compare(const node &first, const node &second)
 {
  if (_available == true)
   return (first.value < second.value);
  else
   return (first.value > second.value);
 }
};
```

Then when I call : `list.sort(myClass::compare);`

I got : `error: no matching function for call to ‘std::list<node>::sort(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’`

Comment: You do know that you don't really have to use `typedef` with structures and classes in C++? The name `s_node` can be used as a type.

Comment: In fact I learned that about an hour ago ^^. But didn't try it yet.(EDIT)

Comment: If you're list needs sorting consider using a `std::deque` or a `std::vector`. http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `myClass::compare` is not a static method. You must make it static to pass it as a predicate for a sort. Or make it global. Also it must be public if it is to be a static class method.

```
typedef struct  s_node
{
    int value;
    int t_node;
};

class myClass
{
private:
    bool _available;

public:
    myClass();
    ~myClass();

    static bool compare(const t_node &first, const t_node &second)
    {
        if (_available == true)
            return (first.value < second.value)
        else
            return (first.value > second.value)
    }
};
```

OR

```
typedef struct  s_node
{
    int value;
    int t_node;
};

class myClass
{
private:
    bool _available;

public:
    myClass();
    ~myClass();
};

bool compare(const t_node &first, const t_node &second)
{
    if (_available == true)
        return (first.value < second.value)
    else
        return (first.value > second.value)
}
```

And you could call it as:

```
list.sort( myClass:compare ); // first example
```

or

```
list.sort( compare ); // second example
```

Comment: Yes, cool. Apart from the "global" word - do you mean a free function? What about a functor? What about some sample code demoing what you mean?

Comment: Or use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) together with an instance of `myClass`. This also solves the problem with using a non-static member variable in the function.

Comment: I do mean free function. You could also use anonymous functions, but this example is enough to get you going.

Comment: You do not need to pass a free function to `sort`; your post reads as this is required, though

Comment: @user1781290: Oh? I didn't know this. I have to run for now, but if you want to edit to make my example more correct, feel free. Otherwise, will research and edit later. Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that's not going to compile, right? It accesses a non-static member.

Comment: First solution try : `In static member function ‘static bool myClass::compare(const node&, const node&)’: error: invalid use of member ‘myClass::_available’ in static member function`, while compiling.

Answer (score 4):

The comparison function in problematic because you use a private member variable in it. That means you can't really use a static member function or a free-standing function or a lambda.

You also have a problem in that the comparison function is private, which means you have to sort the collection from inside a `myClass` object instance.

The first problem can be solved by using [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to bind the member function to a specific object instance. The second problem can be solved by making the function `public` (or by sorting from another member function inside the `myClass` class).

---

You can use `std::bind` like this:

```
// Definition of `list` here somewhere

myClass myObject;

list.sort(std::bind(&myClass::compare, &myObject));
```

Comment: `the comparison function is private` could be public ! =) `std::bind` needs C++ 11 by the way.

Comment: @Elfayer If you do not have C++11 you can use boost::bind or you can create the functor yourself.